# Change values in column based on antoher dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have 2 dataframes, one when i have player stats and his id and second when i have id's and player real name. I want to change column in frist dataframe from player id to player real name pased on second dataframe.

```
data_1 = {'ID_first_player':['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        'ID_second_player':['1', '4', '3', '8'],
        'Points':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
data_2 = {'ID':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8],
        'RealName':['Tom', 'mark', 'nick', 'dan', 'krish', 'jack', 'maxim', 'ken']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
result_data = {'Name_first_player':['Tom', 'mark', 'nick', 'dan'],
        'Name_second_player':['Tom', 'dan', 'nick', 'ken'],
        'Points':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
df_result = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

I tired like this but doesn't work

```
df_1['ID_first_player'] = df_2[df_2['ID'] == df_1['ID_first_player']].iloc[:,1]
```

Can somone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map`:

```py
m = df_2.set_index("ID")["RealName"]
df_1.ID_first_player = df_1.ID_first_player.map(m)
df_1.ID_second_player = df_1.ID_second_player.map(m)

print(df_1)
```

Prints:

```
  ID_first_player ID_second_player  Points
0             Tom              Tom      20
1            mark              dan      21
2            nick             nick      19
3             dan              ken      18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary from df_2 values and then replace values in df_1:

```
d = pd.Series(df_2['RealName'].values, index=df_2['ID']).to_dict()
df_result = df_1.replace(d)
df_result.columns = ['Name_first_player', 'Name_second_player', 'Points']
```

Output:

```
    Name_first_player   Name_second_player  Points
0                 Tom                  Tom      20
1                mark                  dan      21
2                nick                 nick      19
3                 dan                  ken      18
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `join`, which would be the SQL approach to what you want to do.

```
df_realnames = df_1.join(df_2.set_index('ID'), on=['ID_first_player','ID_first_player'], lsuffix='_first_player', rsuffix='_second_player')
```

Then the columns of df_realnames would be "RealName_first_player" and "RealName_second_player", which is actually a more accurate description.